# Images not getting displayed on Apache server

Tags: django, apache, custom-error-pages

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCs2z.png)

I built a website using the Django framework and hosted it on an Apache server. The images are not getting displayed for some reason. It is giving me a 404 error (please see the attached image) but I am sure it is looking at the right place. However, it is fetching other sorts of files like csv but not images. Also, when I run it on a local server, the images are getting displayed. Can someone please help me out?

I tried to change the way I am specifying the path but it is still not working.

Code snippets:

settings.py

```py
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

metrics.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
....

<img src="{% static "images/metrics.jpg" %}" alt="metrics" height="250px" width="500px" />
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just edited the post.